# Import Resource Bundle to vue project

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2, es6-modules

I want to add package [ResourceBundle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resource-bundle) to my vue project.So i installed it:

```
npm install resource-bundle
```

These are export parts in index.js resourcebundle package:

```
export function* loader (locale, dir, baseName) {
    console.log('in loader')//Does not print
    ...
    return new ResourceBundle(require(file))
};

function ResourceBundle (resource) {
    this.resource = resource
}

ResourceBundle.prototype.get = function (key) {
    ...
    return util.format.apply(util, params);
};

export const ResourceBundlee = ResourceBundle
```

Then import it in main.js and use 'loader':

```
import * as ResourceBundle from 'resource-bundle'
console.log(ResourceBundle)
//console:
// ResourceBundlee:ƒ s(t) 
// loader:ƒ r(t,e,n)  
console.log(ResourceBundle.loader('en_US', 
__dirname+'/resources',message').get) 
//console:
//undefined
```

I do not know javascript.Would you please explain what is happening and why does not print 'in loader' and how should i import loader in correct way? thanks

Answer (score 0):

`npm install ResourceBundle` should be `npm install --save resource-bundle`. Try re-installing with the correct package name and the save flag.

After that, check the `package.json` file in your project root directory for `resource-bundle` listed in the `"dependencies"` section.

```
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "resource-bundle": "^0.1.2",
    ...
  }
```

Changed your import statement to:

```
import loader from 'resource-bundle'
```

And call the loader function:

```
let message = loader('en_US', __dirname+'/resources',message')
console.log(message.get('some-key'))
```

Comment: i'm sorry for my mistake in my question. I have installed it correctly actually. command is edited now in the question

Comment: My problem is importing this package to main.js file.

Comment: import loader from 'resource-bundle',
and i get a loader which is 'undefind'

Comment: Looking at the [source on GitHub](https://github.com/RocksonZeta/resource-bundle/blob/master/index.js) now, it appears different than what you've posted. I don't see a `loader` function. Am I looking at the wrong package?

Comment: According to ECMAScript 6 modules syntax,for importing an object I have to export it.  So i changed index.js of resource-bundle in this way.

Comment: I changed  'module.exports = function*(locale, dir, baseName)' to 'export function* loader (locale, dir, baseName)'

Comment: Do you have [co](https://github.com/tj/co) or [koa](https://github.com/koajs/koa) installed?

Comment: Yes, I installed it now. But what has co to do with loader? it's still undefined...

Comment: The documentation says `Resource-bundle must be used in co enviroment,such as koa.`.

Comment: Okey,I have co installed But how to import loader now? I i thought not to change the package files and use require(resource-bundle) instead of importing it. please help me there [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48731457/vue-require-a-package-cannot-assign-to-read-only-property-exports-of-object