# Vue: require a package :cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2, es6-modules

I installed package [resource-bundle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resource-bundle) in my project and now to use it in my main.js:

```
/*main.js*/
var co=require('co');
var loader = require('resource-bundle');
co(function*(){
   ...
   ...
}).catch(onerror);
```

And this is in the [index.js](https://github.com/RocksonZeta/resource-bundle/blob/master/index.js) of resource-bundle package:

```
 /*index.js*/
 module.exports = function*(locale, dir, baseName) {
    ...
    ...
    ...
 }
```

It gets this error:

```
Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Why your module.exports is a function?

It should be Object Literal like this:

```
module.exports = {
key:"value",
intro:"my name is %s,in class %d",
mk:"%s%s%s"
```

}

Comment: This is the index.js file exists in resource-bundle. [link]https://github.com/RocksonZeta/resource-bundle/blob/master/index.js

Comment: There's nothing wrong with setting `module.exports` to a function.